# elasticsearch: Steps to add replica?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a single ES server, in production.

We would now like to add a replica, in another DC, as a warm/hot spare fail over.

I know how to do this on mongo, redis, etc, but cannot seem to find the docs on how to do it to ES. (ES docs seem to assume the systems are all on same subnet, etc)

Comment: ES just needs nodes which can discover each other. It'll take care of shard balancing and master election. Across datacenters, you'll just want to use unicast discovery. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/modules-discovery.html

Comment: @ChrisHeald Thanks! But that doc is not actionable, afaics. I need to know what to do on each system so that the systems know about each other (across data centers), and how to check that they can communicate, etc.

Comment: Standard networking stuff - you'll need the required ports open and the machines will need to be routable to each other, either over the public internet or via a VPN. That's all external to ES stuff, though. Once you have the machines able to talk to each other, you just configure the unicast discovery on each node to discover the other node(s) and off it goes.

Comment: The best advice I can give you in a scenario like this one is to index at the same time in both datacenters. This implies two separate clusters. I wouldn't go with the single-cluster-across-two-datacenters approach, for the reasons @Prabin mentioned in his answer . The alternative is to take snapshots at pre-determined periods of time and restore them in the second DC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elasticsearch exists as a cloud, means if you have replicas they act sort of a master-master mode. If one server is down other will automatically take over. When indexing a documents it indexes in the replica also before returning thereby maintaining consistency of data.

A cluster can have zero or more replicas and it can be configured runtime using the update settings api as below

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/your_index/_settings' -d '
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
    }
}'
```

The replicas will be created only if there is enough nodes running(replica of a shard will never exist in the same node as it's primary). Your cluster will go into yellow state if the replicas could not be assigned.

In your new DC start a new elasticsearch node having same cluster name.
If you are using default configurations you need not do any changes except making same cluster name for the nodes to discover each other else changes may be required to do in the network configuration.

**caution:** it is not recommended to have a replica or elasticsearch nodes for same cluster in separate DC as network latency can impact the performance. Moreover it may affect the cluster stability.

If you intend have a backup of data in a separate DC, you may consider using the [snapshot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html)

Comment: snapshot looks to be way to go.  Would be nice if ES could have an RO replica at another DC, but will take what we can get!