# elasticsearch: Poss to change number of replicas after system is running?

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch 1.7.2 on centos
3 node cluster

This question is how to manage ES config via mods to elasticsearch.yml + restart of elasticsearch service. (Not via api.)

Out of box, the config is:

```
index.number_of_replicas: 1
```

So on a 3 node cluster, any 2 nodes have the whole package.

If I want any 1 node to be complete, I would set:

```
index.number_of_replicas: 2
```

- a) Correct?
- b) Can I just walk up to an existing setup and make this change?
- c) And, can I just walk up , and adjust it up to 2, and down to 1, whenever?  (up to make each node a possible stand alone, down to save disk space)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [elasticsearch: Steps to add replica?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338235/elasticsearch-steps-to-add-replica)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of replica can be changed at any point of time. You can increase or decrease the replica dynamically. There is a good example shown [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#indices-update-settings).

Also please note that , you cant change the number of shards after index creation , but number of replica is open to change via index settings API.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, another way to do this (I have now proven out) is to update the yml file (elasticsearch.yml). Change the element:

```
index.number_of_replicas: 2
```

Up or down, as desired, and restart the elasticsearch service

```
service elasticsearch restart
```

The cluster will go yellow (yellow status) while the replicas are being created/moved, and then will go green.